"OutstandingToken.user" must be a "User" instance
I am getting this error while logging in, This is due to adding 'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist' to my settings.py, but without it everything works fine.
this is the traceback
ValueError at /api/token/
Cannot assign "<TravelSite: TravelSite object (6)>": "OutstandingToken.user" must be a "User" instance.
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/
Django Version:     5.0.6
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:
Cannot assign "<TravelSite: TravelSite object (6)>": "OutstandingToken.user" must be a "User" instance.
Exception Location:     D:\django\travelsite\backend_TravelSite.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py, line 284, in set
Raised during:  tsite.views.CustomTokenObtainPairView
Python Executable:  D:\django\travelsite\backend_TravelSite.venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.12.4
Python Path:
['D:\django\travelsite\backend_TravelSite',
'C:\Python312\python312.zip',
'C:\Python312\DLLs',
'C:\Python312\Lib',
'C:\Python312',
'D:\django\travelsite\backend_TravelSite\.venv',
'D:\django\travelsite\backend_TravelSite\.venv\Lib\site-packages']
models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser




class TravelSite(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)

views.py
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from tsite.models import TravelSite
from tsite.serializers import TravelSiteSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password, check_password
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated


class TravelSiteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TravelSite.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TravelSiteSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        password = self.request.data.get('password')
        hashed_password = make_password(password, hasher='scrypt')
        serializer.save(password=hashed_password)


class CustomTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = request.data.get('username')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        try:
            user = TravelSite.objects.get(username=username)
            if check_password(password, user.password):
                refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
                return Response({
                    'refresh': str(refresh),
                    'access': str(refresh.access_token),
                })
            else:
                return Response({"error": "Invalid credentials"}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        except TravelSite.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({"error": "User does not exist"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)


class LogoutView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            refresh_token = request.data["refresh"]
            token = RefreshToken(refresh_token)
            token.blacklist()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_205_RESET_CONTENT)

        except Exception as e:
            return Response({"error": str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

It should just work right out of the box, but Idk why blocklist is causing this error.
